# Netlogo; Hiker-modell

Tags: netlogo

I'm currently working on a Hiker model in Netlogo.
The hikers walk in a row and the first hiker is the slowest. Overtaking is not allowed. Is there a possibility to build in a function, with which the hikers, after reaching their foreman, take this new speed and stay behind him?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds a like lot the Traffic models from NetLogo's Models Library. I'd suggest you take a look at **Traffic Basic** and **Traffic 2 Lanes** and try to adapt one of them to your problem.

The code from **Traffic 2 Lanes** is a bit more sophisticated, but might also be a more robust base to build on. (And it can be made to work for only one lane, thus preventing overtaking, by setting `number-of-lanes` to `1` in the code tab.)